# When an error occurs in the ActiveAdmin form the /new is removed from the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm creating an Admin page for my model i noticed that if there are errors in your new and edit forms the /new is removed from URL

for example if my url was
/my_model/new

On error it is changed to
/my_model

Is there any way to fix this because I'm writing custom javascript based upon the url if it's new do something if it's edit do something else

Please let me know if anyone knows a fix

Update:

i should've have provided more info what I'm doing and what's causing the issue so I have a model for which I'm creating an admin page using the ActiveAdmin gem

here is my model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    validates :count, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 99 }, allow_nil: true
  end
```

and my active admin page looks something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Task, as: "Tasks" do
  actions :all, except: [:destroy]
  menu label: "Tasks", parent: "Tasks Menu"

  permit_params :name, :count
  
  index do
    id_column
    column :name
    column :count
  end

  show do
    tabs do
      tab :basic do
        attributes_table do
          row :name
          row :count
        end
      end
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    f.inputs "Basic Details" do
      f.input :name     
      f.input :count

      f.actions
    end
  end
end
```

so when you open up a Item or try to create or update a Task the URL goes to either /admin/tasks/new or /admin/tasks/edit

so I need to make some changes using JQuery based upon the URL so I made a script for this which looks something like:

```
var window_location_elements = location.href.split("/");
var length = window_location_elements.length;


if(window_location_elements[length-1] === "edit" || window_location_elements[length-1] === "new"){
  // do something
}
```

So now the issue occurs when lets say i enter a value of count in my input which is not valid there is an error in my form which is shown perfectly but the weird thing that happens is as soon as there is an error the url switches from:

/admin/tasks/new to just /admin/tasks
(same for edit)

Comment: You're falling victim to a classic Rails beginner misconception. In Rails the `new` action just renders a form. The form is POST'ed to  the collection path (for example `/things`) and not a path with a postfix. Your app is working exactly like it should and you should just write your JS differently. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: While you could break with convention over configuration and reconfigure the routes and form to POST to `/things/new` it's better that you actually learn how the framework works (and why) and write JS that fits it. If you include this JS and a description of what it's supposed to accomplish I'm sure we can help you find a better solution.

Comment: @max i added some more information about my issue in the post, so i get it that /new is for the POST request to my model but the issue is once an error occurs inside the form the url is changed which does mess my javascript function, I'm really new to rails started 2 weeks only so I'm not sure whats causing this

Comment: You're still just stuck on the beginner misconception I was talking about. The problem is that your expectations are completely wrong. In Rails flavor rest when creating a resource you send a `POST /things` request. If the resource is valid the server will respond with a redirect to the new resource. If its not valid you render the form again and send it as the response to an invalid form submission. The URL will remain the same as the one the form was posted to.

Comment: Maybe you could run your script based on the existence of an edit <form> or some other HTML element / id / class. (I don't know how the default templates look like in active admin but I assume that they set something based on the page)

Comment: @max i understand that the POST request will always be made through the /things url, what Im not getting is that why is /new being removed from the URL when we are on the same page , or like you said it if the form is rendered again and sent as a response to an invalid form submission is there to move this form to some other url like let's say /things/xyz?

Comment: You're still stuck on the X&Y problem here. "Instead of asking how do I ensure that my JS runs when a resource is created?" you're running around in circles with your idea of hooking your JS logic onto the page URL which is broken. Listen to @Stefan instead. ActiveAdmin sets `"data-rails-controller"` and `"data-rails-action"` attributes on the body element which tell you what the backend is doing. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb#L70C12-L70C32

Comment: I wrote a gem a very long time ago which uses this approach to trigger page specific javascript. While I don't recommend using it as I have been to lazy to maintain it you can use it as a reference for how to implement this. https://github.com/maxcal/pagescript/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/pagescript.js

Comment: @max ohh it get now, you're right i was just running in circles to just make my javascript run, thanks a lot, I'm really slow learner thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a mistake on my end I was only thinking to just make my javascript work as I was only associating the new and edit form with the URL , but that's not ActiveAdmin handles form creation and updation, as in rails if a form is not valid we render the form again and send it as the response to an invalid form submission.

Keeping this in mind and reading more about this I found out that ActiveAdmin updates the `body` element of the DOM to let the server know which form it is.

Next the only thing needed was to update my javascript to handle this, here is the final javascript

```
var bodyClassList = document.body.classList;

if ( bodyClassList.contains("edit") || bodyClassList.contains("new") ||
      bodyClassList.contains("update") || bodyClassList.contains("create") ) {
   // do something
}
```